# Accessing Google Cloud IAP protected resource with bearer token gives error code 13

Tags: google-app-engine, google-iap

I am trying to access a resource protected by Google Cloud IAP from my iOS app.

I am able to login to my Google account from the app and receive an ID token, but I receive the following response with HTTP error code 401 when setting the ID token as Bearer token in the Authorization header for the resource I would like to request.

> "There was a problem with your request. Error code 13"

I tried to send the request with Postman, but this also resulted with the same error.

I use the following code for setting the client ID from the downloaded credentials.plist file.

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "credentials", ofType: "plist") {
   let nsDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
   let clientId = nsDictionary!["CLIENT_ID"] as? String

   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = clientId
   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self;
}
```

Afterwards I sign into Google.

```
if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() {
   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
} else {
   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

After login, I take the idToken and send it to the resource protected by Google Cloud IAP.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
   let token = user.authentication.idToken

   var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

   request.httpMethod = httpMethod
   request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
    }).resume()
}
```

I would expect a successful response, but currently I receive HTTP error code 401 together with the previously mentioned error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** As of July 11th, IAP users should now get a more descriptive error than "Error code 13" when there are problems with the token.

Some examples:

```
$ curl -H 'Authorization: bearer schmearer' $IAP_URL
Invalid IAP credentials: Expected JWT to have 3 parts separated by a '.' but there are 1 parts
$ curl -H 'Authorization: bearer a.b.c' $IAP_URL
Invalid IAP credentials: Base64 decode failed on token: a.b.c
> ^C
msachs@msachs-ubi:~$ curl -H 'Authorization: bearer [real token]' $IAP_URL
Invalid IAP credentials: JWT signature is invalid
msachs@msachs-ubi:~$ curl -H 'Authorization: bearer [real token]' $IAP_URL
Invalid IAP credentials: JWT audience doesn't match this application ('aud' claim (5939454960-[...]) doesn't match expected value (1042451928015-[...]))
```

"Error code 13" means that IAP doesn't like something about your token. In this case, I think the issue is that you need to set the [serverClientId property](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in#ae214ed831bb93a06d8d9c3692d5b35f9) to the client ID used by your IAP app. You can find this by going to the [IAP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/security/iap), finding the resource you're connecting to, and selecting "Edit OAuth Client" from the overflow menu in that resource's table row.

[Our documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_mobile_app) seems to be missing that step, I'll get that taken care of. (Thanks for flagging that!)

Comment: This is now documented at https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_mobile_app .