# Planned Support for Kubeflow Pipeline Uploads via API?

Tags: kubeflow

Is it possible to upload a Kubeflow Pipeline using an API call using the Kubeflow Pipelines Python SDK?

There is the following specs for making API calls: https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/pipelines/reference/api/kubeflow-pipeline-api-spec/

However, when I try uploading a pipeline using the route "/apis/v1beta1/pipelines/upload" in PostMan, I get the following error:

```
There was a problem with your request. Error code 13
```

I am sure I need to add some Authorization headers, but before I go that hacky route, I wonder if there are plans to add this functionality to the Python SDK. Please let me know if you guys have an idea, or a better way to set up the request for uploading pipelines outside the Kubeflow Pipelines UI!

Comment: Given the error code, the problem here seems indeed related to authentication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717074/accessing-google-cloud-iap-protected-resource-with-bearer-token-gives-error-code. Either way, adding this functionality to the python SDK currently seems an open issue: https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/1130

Answer (score 1):

By now, it's possible indeed to upload a pipeline with the `kfp` python sdk:

```
import kfp
client = kfp.Client()
client.upload_pipeline('path/to/pipeline.yaml', pipeline_name=name)
```

See the [docs](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/kfp.client.html#kfp.Client.upload_pipeline) for a full API reference.